# How to write a driver for opencl?

Tags: driver, opencl

How would one start to develop an opencl interface for a new device?
Where are the ressources for this type of work?

I had a quick look at the [specification](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenCL/specs/3.0-unified/html/OpenCL_Ext.html) but find it a bit hard to navigate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two options:

1. Start from scratch. Will be very tedious and highly unlikely to ever produce a compliant implementation that'd pass all the Khronos tests (also, you're very unlikely to even get an access to the test suite)
2. Fork an existing open source implementation, such as POCL or Beignet. POCL will probably the easiest to extend. This way you're still not going to get an access to the Khronos test suite, but some people who do have an access contribute to POCL, so the chance of it being close to compliant is very good.